# jQuery xhr object properties in ajax function callbacks

Tags: jquery, xmlhttprequest, httpresponse

given an ajax callback like for example...

```
function showResponse(responseText, statusText, xhr) { }
```

How can I get a status/reponse code or something from the `xhr` object?

```
alert(xhr);              // [object]
alert(xhr.status);       // undefined
alert(xhr.statusText);   // undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use dojo framework and then output the xhr object with

```
console.dir(xhr)
```

Otherwise you could print all elements from xhr object with a for each loop

```
for (var n in xhr) {
  alert(n + " => " + xhr[n]);
}
```

Note that i dont try this code so the code could include a bug ;-)